# Real Analysis; injective and surjective functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $f$ and $g$ functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ given by $$g(x)= x^2-x$$ and $$f(x)= -\sin x$$

i) Is $g$ injective?

ii) is $g$ surjective?

iii) is $g$ invertible?

iv) is $f$ injective?

v) is $f$ surjective?

I would really appreciate help with this question.

Comment: What are your thoughts so far? What is the definition of injectivity/surjectivity? These are easy things to check.

Comment: When you want to decide if a function is injective (surjective) or not, you must specify domain and codomain: $g$ -e.g- would be bijective if it was defined $g:\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: Read the beginner friendly stuff & help yourself by writing on paper: : https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/injective-surjective-bijective.html

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

(i) For $g$ to be injective, we need to show that if $x_1\neq x_2$, then $g(x_1) \neq g(x_2)$.

- $g(0) = 0$ and $g(1) = 0$. So is $g$ injective?

(ii) Since $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, for $g$ to be surjective, we need for *every* $y \in \mathbb R$, there is some $x \in \mathbb R$ such that $g(x) = y$.

- Does there exist an $x$ such that $g(x) = -3$? So is $g(x)$ surjective?

(iii) A function is invertible if and only if it is injective *and* surjective.

iv) To show that $f$ is injective you need to show that if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ then $x_1 = x_2$, or equivalently, if $x_1\neq x_2$, then $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$.

- What is $f(0)?$ What is $f(\pi)?$ Can $f(x)$ be injective?

v) To show that $f$ is surjective you need to show that for every $y$ in the range of $f$ that there exists an $x$ in the domain such that $f(x)=y$.

Comment: for the function x^2+ 5x on the same domain can it be shown it is injective as shown below?              a^2 +5a = b^2 + 5b,  a(a+5) = b(b+5),    ( multiply both sides by ab),   b(a+5) = a(b+5),  ab +5b = ab+ 5a,   therefore b=a

Comment: No. Note that $x^2 + 5x = 0$ when $x_1 = 0$ and when $x_2 = -5$. So it cannot be injective because there exists $x_1\neq x_2$ but $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$

Answer (score 0):

i) To show that $g$ is injective you want to show that if $g(x)=g(y)$ then $x=y$.

ii) To show that $g$ is surjective you want to show that for every $y$ in the range of $g$ that there exists an $x$ in the domain of $g$ such that $g(x)=y$.

iii) To show that $g$ is invertible you could just find its inverse. It will be invertible if it is injective. If it is not injective then it is not invertible.

For $f$ you do the same thing as in i) and ii)